# how to get the actual translation of a uiview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, transform

I have an uiview in which I draw my own map with a dimension of say 1000 * 1000.

I am moving and scaling the map with CGAffineTransform....... (Translate, Scale) transformations.

Lets say the upper left coordinate of my map after translation is 20 (x),10(y), because I translatet the map 20 to the left and 10 up.

Is there a way to get the coordinate of the upperleft corner of my map from the view ? (I know I could maintain my own metadata for this and update my metadata after a translation by my self.)

Answer (score 1):

```
extension CGAffineTransform {

    var translation: CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: tx, y: ty)
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add some meaningful explanation along with your code so that the OP can better understand and solve her/his problem.